Operation amplifier optimized layout- Noise- Signal Integrity
I was watching a seminar from Fedevel academy, in this seminar as all the datasheet has mentioned, we need to remove GND and PWR plane underneath the negative inverting pin and the output pin of the operational amplifier (It is important to avoid ground in the areas under and around the input and output of the Stray capacitance created between the ground plane and the input and output pads of a device is detrimental to high speed amplifier performance. Stray capacitance at the inverting input,
along with the amplifier input capacitance, lowers the phase
margin and can cause instability. Stray capacitance at the output
creates a pole in the feedback loop, which can reduce phase margin
and can cause the circuit to become unstable) :

For example in the datasheet of OPA837 it is mentioned as follow:

This raise the following question for me:

Do we need to just remove the GND and PWR plane just underneath the inverting pin and output pin? or also we need to remove the GND and PWR underneath the feedback trace as well?



My second question would be if we need to remove the GND and PWR plan under the feedback trace as well then we can make another critical problem related to signal integrity. As a general rule for high speed PCBs we need to provide a solid GND plan underneath the signal traces, otherwise it can cause signal integrity issue:


Thanks in advance for your answers and helps:

@ Andy aka Hello Andy would you please let me know if you have an idea about this question?
